# How in c++ builder export registry to *.reg file?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, vcl

I'm use reg->SaveKey("Software", "D:\1.reg"). But getting empty file, without data.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
      TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
      reg->RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      reg->OpenKey("Software",0);;
      reg->SaveKey("Software","D:\\1.reg");
      delete reg;

}
```

Comment: what is reg? what library do you use for accessing the registry?

Comment: Library-TRegistry. TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry(KEY_ALL_ACCESS);

Comment: please provide more code. also KEY_READ may be sufficient, as it can be a permission problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SaveKey` is a loose wrapper around [`RegSaveKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724917%28VS.85%29.aspx), the documentation of which states:

> The calling process must have the `SE_BACKUP_NAME` privilege enabled. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges.

User tokens do not normally have the `SE_BACKUP_NAME` privilege enabled. In order to meet this requirement you need to:

1. Run as administrator.
2. Add the `SE_BACKUP_NAME` privilege to your user token.

The other requirement you must adhere to is that the output file must not exist before you call `SaveKey`.

See this [EDN article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10348) for C++ code illustrating the method.

Comment: I set *reg to KEY_READ, but it's problem remained.

Comment: You don't need to call `OpenKey` since you specify the key in `SaveKey`. `SaveKey` is a loose wrapper around the Win32 API `RegSaveKey`. Try to call `RegSaveKey` directly and then look at the error code that it returns to see why it is failing.

Comment: Another point. I have already, in a previous question, told you about KEY_ALL_ACCESS. Please can you read more carefully the advice you are given so as not to make the same mistakes again and again.

Comment: Yet another. Why are you doing this? What's wrong with `regedit` or `reg save`?

Comment: David, mistake not in KEY_READ or KEY_ALL_ACCESS. I'm carefully reading your advices, and thank to you for them. But when i creating the file, it's writing to right directory, but not contains any data. And how i could to call "regedit" from my program? And for what?

Comment: Your information for visual studio, isn't it? But i programming in builder now.

Comment: No my information is not for Visual Studio. `TRegistry.SaveKey` is implemented in Pascal and it calls Win32 API function RegSaveKey. In this case mistake may not be KEY_ALL_ACCESS, but if you didn't fix that you would have failed to open the key. Not that you need to open the key anyway! All the same, you simply need to run as admin to get `SaveKey` to work.

Comment: Ok. Let's try from another part. I'm admin on my computer (that logical), but i don't get data in my backup file. Why? I set KEY_READ, I don't use OpenKey. Only SaveKey.

Comment: You are running with UAC I presume and even though you are an admin, a standard process doesn't run with admin privileges. Run it elevated and it will work. You can see exactly this if you use `reg save` to do the same action. In fact, why are you know doing `reg save`?

Comment: so running as admin didn't solve it? What does GetLastError return?

Comment: I not received errors. No one. How I can to get GetLastError?

Comment: just call GetLastError. Are you running as admin?

Comment: Do you know that when you finally get this to work the result is a binary .dat file?

Comment: I know, that registry will be save in a binary data format. But i receive an empty file. What's wrong with it? reg-SaveKey("Software", "D:\\1.reg")? I must to save in a *.dat? Try to save in a 1.dat. Result same as *.reg. Empty. And code of error "0". From GetLastError().

Comment: I'm admin of my comp. And i try to run my program with privileges. Right button click.

Comment: sorry RegSaveKey returns errors directly as function return value rather than using GetLastError. So you should call RegSaveKey directly and check return value.

Comment: @Viktor Sorry I've been so terribly slow to work this one out. See the updated answer. I've now done this myself and can confirm that it works.

Comment: I try to do as this `void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
HANDLE ProcessToken;

if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &ProcessToken))
{
 SetPrivilege(ProcessToken, SE_BACKUP_NAME, TRUE);
 RegSaveKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, UnicodeString("D:\\1.reg").w_str(), SE_BACKUP_NAME);
}
   TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
   reg->RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
   reg->SaveKey("Software","D:\\1.reg");
   delete reg;


}`

Comment: The code in the article works. Once you have acquired the SE_BACKUP_NAME privilege the call to reg->SaveKey works. You can either call reg->SaveKey or RegSaveKey but don't call both. Surely you can understand that reg->SaveKey simply calls RegSaveKey. Do you have the source code to the VCL in your C++ Builder edition? Can you read Delphi/Pascal code?

Comment: Want w_char. And... and next variant worked! `void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
HANDLE ProcessToken;

if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &ProcessToken))
{
 SetPrivilege(ProcessToken, SE_BACKUP_NAME, TRUE);
    TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
   reg->RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
   reg->SaveKey("Software","D:\\1.reg");
   delete reg;
}



}`

Answer (score 0):

Next variant worked!

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
HANDLE ProcessToken;

if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &ProcessToken))
{
    SetPrivilege(ProcessToken, SE_BACKUP_NAME, TRUE);
          TRegistry *reg=new TRegistry(KEY_READ);
      reg->RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      reg->SaveKey("Software","D:\\1.reg");
      delete reg;
}



}
```